# ANGULARJS CON GOOGLE MAPS

Tags: ajax, json, angularjs, google-maps

primera vez que empleare AngularJS con la Api de Google Maps, la cuestión es que use una .directive para poder mostrar el mapa de google.

```
app.directive("myMaps",function(){

return{

    restrict:'E',
    template:'<div></div>',
    replace:true,
    scope: {
      lat: '=',
      long: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(scope.lat,scope.long);
          var mapOptions = {
            center: myLatLng,
            zoom: 16,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
          };
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(attrs.id),
              mapOptions);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            title:"Posicion"
          });
          marker.setMap(map);

    }
};
});
```

El problema es lo siguiente, estoy empleando una tabla que muestra varios centros en un datatable, y con un botón "localización" mostrar un modal que muestre la ubicación del centro gracias a las coordenadas que se solicitan y envía la respectiva función del controller. Asi estoy utilizando la directiva y coger la latitud y longitud del centro.

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <p>{{ centro.razon }}</p> <br>
  <p>{{ centro.latitud }}, {{ centro.longitud }}</p>
 <my-maps id="map-canvas" lat= "centro.latitud" long= "centro.longitud"></my-maps></div>
```

Lamentablemente, no me logra mostrar cuando envío las coordenadas de esa manera, solo aparece cuando pongo coordenadas por defecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera saber en que parte me estoy confundiendo, ya que esa directiva si funciona cuando por ejemplo escribo lat = -5.53268 long = -78.43484, el cuadro normal sale el mapa. Pero con lo que mando me sale así gris :/

Comment: Revisa la consola de Chrome para descartar algún error.. también seria excelente que copiaras tu controller para poder orientarnos mejor :)

Comment: ya revise tambien en la consola de Chrome, sale el mismo error, solo cuando pongo valores por defecto el mapa sale normal. no entiendo porque no sale. Si como muestro en la imagen, la latitud y longitud se manda normal :/

Answer (score 1):

Agrega el estilo que requiere para que se muestre el mapa, prueba con esto en tu css:

```
#idDelDivDondeEstaTuMapa{
    height: 100%;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Aquí la [documentación oficial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial). Espero te funcione, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Antes de nada, disculpe por mi español.

Vi este problema algunas veces y la razón es que su Bootstrap modal existe en el DOM antes que se aparece al usuario. Entonces, la directiva "myMaps" no esta visible y no toma espacio cuando el usuario presiona el buton y la biblioteca de Google Maps omite el proceso de representación del mapa.

**La mejor solución es la siguiente:**

1. Ya que su *$('#modal').show()* esta adentro de su controlador,
   necesita emitir un evento hasta su directiva. Ponga eso adentro de su controlador, después su *$('#modal').show()*.

   ```
   $('#modal').on('shown', function() {
        $scope.$broadcast('modalReady', function () {
             // No necesita nada aquí..
        });
   });
   ```
2. Finalmente, debe escuchar para el evento *modalReady* en su directiva y actualizar la dimension del mapa.

   ```
   $scope.$on('modalReady', function() {
       google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
   });
   ```

No he probado el código pero estoy seguro que funciona.